# Selenium error: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium in a python script on ubuntu. When I try to do: driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op), I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Stacktrace:
#0 0x7fdb77bcba23 <unknown>
#1 0x7fdb77696e18 <unknown>
#2 0x7fdb776bce12 <unknown>
#3 0x7fdb776b934d <unknown>
#4 0x7fdb776b591a <unknown>
#5 0x7fdb776f074a <unknown>
#6 0x7fdb776ea883 <unknown>
#7 0x7fdb776c03fa <unknown>
#8 0x7fdb776c14c5 <unknown>
#9 0x7fdb77bfb16d <unknown>
#10 0x7fdb77c115bb <unknown>
#11 0x7fdb77bfce75 <unknown>
#12 0x7fdb77c11e85 <unknown>
#13 0x7fdb77bf086f <unknown>
#14 0x7fdb77c2cae8 <unknown>
#15 0x7fdb77c2cc68 <unknown>
#16 0x7fdb77c47aad <unknown>
#17 0x7fdb77106609 <unknown>
```

I don;t understand what is the reson. In addition, I check the path of chromedrvier and it is correct.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

ser = Service("/home/danielr/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/97.0.4692.71/chromedriver")
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the next chrome options:

I've also utilized `ChromeDriverManager`, since it present in your imports.
This guarantees you'll not meet the Chrome/chromedriver version mismatch issue.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

#ser = Service("/home/danielr/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/97.0.4692.71/chromedriver")

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=op)
```